# How to let Emacs display with which command line arguments it was invoked?

Tags: applications

I am using Samsung Galaxy S10+ on Android 12. I'm using the Emacs app from F-Droid. However, the top-left corner of my phone is covered, and the top line is too small to hit the icons, even with the help of a pen. Thus, I have to make some settings in Emacs.

Normally, this is to be done by command line options when Emacs is invoked. But in Android, I can only hit the icon of Emacs, I have no opportunity to influence the invocation of Emacs.

When Emacs is beginning to run, I would be able to give Emacs commands to alter its invocation settings. For this, I must get with what parameters Emacs was invoked.

Can you tell me the command to let Emacs report how Emacs was invoked? As Vim does with the Ex-command

```
":echo v:argv"
```

Comment: When talking about third party apps please always provide a link to the app in the app store.

Comment: This question is better suited for Emacs Stack Exchange